# MongoDB data matching and fetching issue while querying on an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to fetch data from the MongoDB. Since I am new into Node.Js and MongoDB. I am not able to get the data.

I am passing primary category and secondary category to an API where I want to match the primary and secondary category with the array field "category" which is having two indexes 0 and 1 ,in the 0 index primary category is there and in the 1 index secondary categories are there separated by ~ .

Below is my code to get the data according to primary category but I want to get the data by matching the primary and secondary category  from the db.

```
ProductModel
.find({ category : { $all : [req.body.primary] }})
.select('id link brand title description category image images in_stock price sale_price merchant_number part_number GroupID status promotion attributes tags currency updated -_id')
.then((productList) => {
  response.status = 200;
  response.msg = 'Success';
  response.count = productList.length;
  response.data = productList
  res.json(response);
})
.catch(() => {
  response.status = 500;
  response.msg = 'connection error';
  response.data = [];
  res.json(response);
});
```

**Sample Doc :**

[image: Database structure screenshot]

So I wanted to input something like `['Health','women']` & get docs where all of these elements in category array exists, kind of regex search on array elements.

Can Someone help me out to get the data from the db.

Comment: what do you mean by this :: *but i want to get the data by matching the primary and secondary category from the db* ? Do you want records where you've both primary & secondary ? Then that case you can just do `.find({ category : { $all : [req.body.primary, req.body.secondary] }})`

Comment: Have you seen my database structure in the image provided.inside the category field there are two indexes 0 and 1 . I want to match 0 index value as "Health" and 1 index value as "women",but in the 1 indexes values are ~ seperated how to match these and get the data

Comment: Ok, so you wanted to match send ['Health', 'women'] to category & get the doc out ?? If that's what you need then your question is unclear !! Can you confirm on that..

Comment: Yes. In the category field 1st index values are considered as my secondary categories in that sample data image provided the 1st index values are "tes~men~women" so here "tes" is a secondary category ,"men" is another secondary category and "women" is another secondary category. I am not able to match the value and get the result

Comment: You can try this :: `db.getCollection('AddToSet').find({$and: [{category : {$in : [/women/]}}, {category : {$in : ['Health']}}]})`

Comment: sorry bro, Your code is working fine

I am getting the desired output
Is it  expensive to use this query if i want to fetch 10000 records

Comment: Yes ,I got the records whichever having the "Health " and "women" inside the category ,Thank you so much.

If i use this query to fetch many data will it slow down the process?

Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Querying on 10k docs is not a big deal, You can have an index on array field `category`, As it's an array - indexes will be created for every element in an array, So there will be 20K indexes at the end(If **category** array in each doc has 2 elements), which is also not a big deal. Querying using regex can be less efficient compared to others, but given conditions we need to do that !! I hope performance wise - With the dataset size & with this query you wouldn't see any issues..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208612/discussion-between-sarathchandran-and-whoami).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've to query with input as `['Health', 'women']` & get the documents which has both listed & also get the documents which has something like this : `category : ["Health", "tes~men~women"]` then you can try below query :

**Query :**

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      category: {
        $in: [
          /\bwomen\b/
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      category: {
        $in: [
          "Health"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

**Js Code :**

```
const secondary = req.body.secondary
const primary = req.body.primary
db.collection.find({
    $and: [
        {
            category: {
                $in: [
                    new RegExp(`\\b${secondary}\\b`, 'i')
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            category: {
                $in: [
                    primary
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: In this if i am passing ['Health', 'men'] then also i will get results which includes women also ,since the "women" word ends with "men" so how can i sort this if i pass ['Health', 'men'] it should only return results set of ['Health', 'men']

Comment: Basically this is a dynamic process ,the "Health" can be changed to "clothing & accessories " ,"Jewellery & Watches" and so on
and the "women" can be changed to "men" ,"boy" and so on.
This is for a e-commerce website where user selects a primary category("Health","clothing & accessories " ,"Jewellery & Watches") and secondary category ("men","women","boy") 
there will be may primary and secondary categories ,so as i said earlier in the category array 0 index is considered as primary category(Health) and 1st index as considered secondary category (men~women~test123)

Comment: This is working fine

ProductModel.find({$and: [{category : {$in : [/\bmen\b/]}}, {category : {$in : [req.body.primary]}}]})

can you tell me how can i make it dynamic:

ProductModel.find({$and: [{category : {$in : [/\breq.body.secondary\b/]}}, {category : {$in : [req.body.primary]}}]})

Comment: Like this way :
ProductModel.find({$and: [{category : {$in : [/\breq.body.secondary\b/]}}, {category : {$in : [req.body.primary]}}]})

Comment: It is working as expected "[{category : {$in : [/\bmen\b/]}}" but i want to pass the value inside the condition like this [{category : {$in : [/\breq.body.secondary\b/]}

Comment: var test=req.body.secondary;
[{category : {$in : [/\btest\b/]}}

this way it is not working ,so i am not able to resolve it ,if you can help to find out then please

Comment: I am very new to this node.js and mongo db and of course i have checked few links online but it could not solve my issue since you are good at these things and i thought you may help without posting a new question so asked here sorry for that.

Comment: it is working in the expected way ,thank you for helping me out of the box